# How to enable the mysql database driver in tomcat 7?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jdbc, jax-rs

I am creating a rest webservice using JAX-RS. the backend classes run normally when I run it as a java application. But when i run it on the server and try to access a resource like:

```
http://localhost:8080/WS/rest/metric/10
```

I get the following exception:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (Database.java:42) - Exception occured: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (Database.java:42) - Exception occured: No suitable driver  found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
Jun 19, 2012 11:27:29 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse  mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP  container
java.lang.NullPointerException
.....
```

the first two lines are logs that i have in my database connection method:

```
public static Connection connect()
{
    try
    {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(domain, username, password);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception occured: "+ e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

the failure to find the driver is causing NullPointerException. 
I have copied the driver jar file to WEB-INF/lib. But still the problem is the same.

Here is the full exception trace:

```
 Jun 19, 2012 11:27:29 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hp.silas.dao.EstimationDAOImpl.getLatestResult(EstimationDAOImpl.java:126)
at com.hp.silas.ws.EstimationResource.getLastEstimation(EstimationResource.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please print the stacktrace and post it here in question `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: What is the code at `EstimationDAOImpl.java:126`

Comment: So where have you initialized the connection `con` ?

Comment: con = Database.connect(); in line 91 of the same file. But it returns Null because of the driver not being recognized. So the question is how to make the driver available from the server perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing part was registering the driver by using this line:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

so the connection method will look like:

```
public static Connection connect()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
        return DriverManager.getConnection(domain, username, password);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception occured: "+ e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's reasonable to put the load of the database driver in somewhere where the exception bubbles up in a “painful” way; after all, missing it is definitely fatal to everything else. Returning `null` isn't going to make things better!

Answer (score 0):

Register the driver?

```
DriverManager.registerDriver("...");
```

Comment: Could you please explain where shall i add this , and where would i get the driver object from?

Comment: `registerDriver` is (normally) not for use by people using the driver. It is called by the driver itself on classloading using `Class.forName("<fqn of driver">)`.